# How To get Name Parent On Inside Page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

how to get page name  and i'm inside this page in wordpress
how to get sub menu inside all page
Each page comes in its sub menu

ex: http://fxmarvel.com/etfs/

[Samle This Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRmMA.png)

Comment: Your question is not clearer. Please try to add more info, what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: here example website
http://fxmarvel.com/promotions/

Comment: In case there is any inside page
Retrieve  Sub menu Special this page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sidebar.
In Wordpress Design > Menu > Add Menu and name it sidebar.
Now you need to add all pages in this sidebar what you want.

After that you add the following code to your container where you will show this menu:

```
<?php add_shortcode('menu', 'print_menu_shortcode'); ?>
```

You need to add it in your template. You can define the subpage template in "pages" on the right side.